# Access block from included file

Tags: twig

I want to access a block inside an included file.
Something like:

```
{#template A #}
some HTML
{% block blockA %}
{% endblock blockA %}
    some HTML  
{% block blockB %}
{% endblock blockB %}
some HTML

{#template B #}
{% extends A %}
{% block blockA %}
{% include C %}
some HTML
{% endblock %}

{#template C #}
{% block blockB %}
  some HTML
{% endblock%}
```

All the HTML that i put on template C didnt go inside "blockB".

Comment: Can you not add a blockB to template B that includes template C?
ie:
`{% block blockB %}
    {% include 'templateC.html.twig' %}
{% endblock %}`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `embed` instead of `include`.

[Twig Documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/embed.html)